# Adding column to a resultset in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on SP, I want to add a column to a resultset. Normally this would not be a proble, but here I'm using an Exec to fill one temp-table. To that temp-table I want to add one column.

Some prestuff that puts data in one of the temp-tables with some conditions

```
declare @RowCount int

set @RowCount = 1
create table #Temp_HS (row int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, h varchar(30))
Create table #tmpS (K varchar(100), 
U varchar(100), Counter int, H varchar(100))


--Puts data in one temp_table with employees
insert into #Temp_HS (h)
select Login from database.dbo.Users
where Old <> 1
and TC in ('A_1', 'A_2')
and Login not in ('Steve', 'Peter', 'Gabs')

--Declaring my counter here, it sets the MaxRow which is 19 in this case
declare @Counter int 
set @Counter = (select Max(row) from #Temp_HS)

select * from #Temp_HS
-- Looping, That my RowCount must be less or Equal to Counter which is 19.
while @RowCount <= @Counter
begin
```

Set User which was originally from the Database Login which is declared as H in the temp table.

```
declare @user varchar(30)
select @user = h from #Temp_HS where row = @RowCount
```

Here comes the tricky part, this is the Stored procedure that inserts 3 columns into a temp
table, here I want to add one colum which in this case is h from Temp_HS to the resultset.

```
INSERT INTO #tmpS
EXEC  Database.dbo.getListCount @user,
param, 
param, 
param, 
'something',
param 



set  @RowCount = @RowCount +1
end

drop table #Temp_HS
```

If you need any further information just ask! :)

Basically I want to add one more column to the results of my Exec SP that inserts the result into a temp_table

Comment: Can't you add the column later? In the next statement for example? And then insert the `@user` variable?

Comment: How do you mean? Something like Insert into TempS colX Select @User?

Comment: No, I meant something like `ALTER TABLE #tmpS ADD NewColumn varchar(20)`

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT INTO .. EXEC` requires that the table you are inserting into already exists, e.g.

```
-- Given this preexisting proc
CREATE PROC dbo.getListCount @user INT, -- other params
AS
   SELECT @User as Col1, 
          'SomeVarChar' as Col2
   FROM [SomeTable];


-- In your code, create the temp table to hold the data
CREATE TABLE #tmpS
(
   Col1 INT,
   Col2 NVARCHAR(100),
   NewColumnH VARCHAR(30) -- Add the additional column up front
   -- etc.
);
```

This is called as

```
INSERT INTO #tmpS(Col1, Col2)
   EXEC dbo.getListCount, @User;
```

If you then need to do do further processing on your temp table, do this after the PROC call:

```
UPDATE ts
   SET NewColumnH = t.h 
   FROM #tmpS ts INNER JOIN #Temp_HS th on th.row = @RowCount;
```

Comment: The thin gis that the SP I'm using is filling the #TmpS table with data, I'm using it in a Loop so I can get data for each user, to get som statistics. The way it is now my result is 19 tables since we have 19 users. I want to add the @User to a column in the same table giving me a wider result and in one table so I can fill and later on call it with some other conditions.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, although the SP I'm executing is creating a unique table with data. Why do you do the Create Proc? The SP already exists.

Comment: I was just trying to match up the proc to the temp table example - obviously your proc already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Actually inner join doesnt work as desireed on temp tables that is why I used this solution. Since I already had @User in a variable I choose to do this update instead.

```
UPDATE ts
SET NewColumnH = @User 
FROM #tmpS ts
where ts.Column is null
```